# getting XMLNode attribute's values

Tags: asp.net, xml, vb.net, xpath

I am working on asp.net application. I have a function like this:

```
   Public Function ExtractText(node As XmlNode) As String

   End Function
```

I need to pass following XML as input to above function:

```
<myrequirements Id="7743" Type="tcg_Concept20_sc_323256419566173_context" StartNode="2724" EndNode="2869">
</myrequirements>
```

Then I need to get StartNode and EndNode attributes values.

Do I need to use XPath. Please suggest.

Regards,
Asif

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try using `node.Attributes("StartNode").Value` and `node.Attributes("EndNode").Value` which will give you the values of those 2 attributes assuming the XmlNode instance passed as argument contains the XML node shown in your question.